# Angular http.get not working, but http.post works

Tags: php, angular, post, get, xampp

GET calls aren't working, this is the error message in the console:

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse:
{"headers":
  {"normalizedNames"{}, "lazyUpdate":null}, 
  "status":200, 
  "statusText":"OK",
  "url":"http://localhost:4200/api/php/services/global/validateSession.php",
  "ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse",
  "message":"Http failure during parsing for 
 http://localhost:4200/api/php/services/global/validateSession.php",
  "error":{
     "error":{},
     "text":"<?php\r\nsession_start();\r\nif(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){\r\n\techo json_encode(array('sesionActiva' => false, 'mensaje' => 'Sesion inactiva.'));\r\n}\r\nelse\r\n{\r\n\techo json_encode(array('sesionActiva' => true, 'mensaje' => 'Sesion activa.'));\r\n}\r\n?>"
  }
}
```

the get calls are't being interpreted, but my post calls work fine, I am using xampp and angular with php for back-end.

Comment: Is the get method supported for the service

Comment: yes, it was working perfectly fine yesterday, didn't change a thing and today it isn't